# Telerik MVC Grid Conditional DetailView?

Tags: if-statement, telerik-grid

I am using Telerik Grid.

I have a situation I have to populate detail view based on a condition. Can anyone give me an idea, how can i switch it?

Here is my detail view code

```
 .DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
            Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                .Name("TabStrip_<#= PID #>")
                .SelectedIndex(0)
                .Items(items =>
                {
                items.Add().Text("Details").LoadContentFrom("PDetails", "Med", new { id = "<#= PID #>" });
               })
                .ToHtmlString()
    ))
```

I would like to make this work something like this.

```
 .DetailView(details => details.ClientTemplate(
            Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
                .Name("TabStrip_<#= PID #>")
                .SelectedIndex(0)
                .Items(items =>
                {
                    if(RxTpe == "New")
                    {
                        items.Add().Text("Details").LoadContentFrom("case1", "case1", new { id = "<#= PID #>" });
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         items.Add().Text("Details2").LoadContentFrom("case2", "case2", new { id = "<#= PID #>" });
                     }
                })
                .ToHtmlString()
    ))
```

Can any one help me, how can I do this?

Comment: So, what happened? Why unaccepted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "if statement" when you are defining the "Items" collection.

```
.Items(items =>
{
    if(RxTpe == "New")
    {
        items.Add().Text("Details").LoadContentFrom("case1", "case1", new { id = "<#= PID #>" });
    }
    else
    {
        items.Add().Text("Details2").LoadContentFrom("case2", "case2", new { id = "<#= PID #>" });
     }
 })
```

Comment: if(RxTpe == "New") RxType is not accessible here

Comment: I can do nothing about it if your wrote your code wrong. It is your duty to write it accessible here. I know nothing about your code. You could call it with Model.RxType or ViewBag.RxType etc. But the answer was that it is possible to write something like this, with accesible variables of course.

Comment: thanks for trying to help me. if you have read my question fully. I have already wrote the code you suggested. and my question was will i be able to access RxTpe in items(items=> ? I am still looking for a way to access the Model Properties in item(item=>